# Where can I download virtual machines for VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

What are the alternatives to [VMWare's Virtual Applicance Marketplace](http://www.vmware.com/appliances/])?

Comment: i would swap the 2 questions, the general case is more usefull than just ubuntu-vms

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The site [virtualbox.wordpress.com/images/](http://virtualbox.wordpress.com/images/) looks like a good alternative to VMWare's Virtual Applicance Marketplace.

You can find Ubuntu images at [virtualbox.wordpress.com/images/ubuntu/](http://virtualbox.wordpress.com/images/ubuntu/) and there even some Ubuntu variants (Kubuntu, Xubuntu) available, if you're interested in those.

Answer (score 0):

You can install and create your own ubuntu installation with virtualbox and a ubuntu CD.

Comment: the question was about an alternative for vmwares virtual appliance ... "preinstalled", "ready to use", "out of the box" virtual machines...